# How to add a menu item to Rgui?

Tags: r, user-interface

I would like to add a "check for updates" menu item in the "Help" tab in the Rgui (on Windows).

I've already created the [R function to check for updates](http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/03/updating-r-from-r-on-windows-using-the-installr-package/), and now I wish to add it to the Rgui (ideally, with a massage box poping out with the results, or even a check-box for further actions by the user).

I'd appreciate any ideas on what functions to look into for doing this (if at all possible using base R, and if not - what packages might offer this option).

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks  G. Grothendieck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example - let's say you wanted to add a new menu called Update and wanted to add a menu item that updates all the packages with 'ask' set to FALSE

```
winMenuAdd("Update")
winMenuAddItem("Update", "Update R packages", "update.packages(ask = F)")
```

Comment: Dason, just to update: thank to your help, I've updated the installr package - and it now has a full fledged GUI (on Windows):  https://github.com/talgalili/installr